# Proper way to save data in hdf5 file to speed up numpy matrix slicing?

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

What I have:

1. numpy matrix, `size = (n, m)`
2. row names, `size = n`

What I want:

- Create HDF5 file,
- save numpy matrix with row names properly.
- use this hdf5 file to calculate cosine similarity between two vectors / matrices.

The size of these vectors / matrices are always different.

What I have tried:

```py
import h5py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

vecs = np.random.rand(50000, 150)
names = np.random.choice(range(10000, 100000), size=50000)

# hdf5 way
with h5py.File('test.h5', mode='w', libver='latest') as f:
    f.create_dataset('vectors', shape=(150,),  dtype=np.float16, compression='gzip', compression_opts=9)

    for name, vec in zip(names, vecs):
        f.attrs[str(name)] = vec

# memory-map way
mmap = np.memmap(filename='test.mymemmap', shape=(50000, 150), dtype='float16', mode='w+', order='F')
name_ind = dict()

for i, (name, vec) in enumerate(zip(names, vecs)):
    mmap[i] = vec
    name_ind[name] = i 

# test case
target_name = np.random.choice(names, size=1)
target_names = np.random.choice(names, size=10000)

# 1-2 sec on my pc
with h5py.File('test.h5','r') as f:
    a = f['vectors']   

    vec1 = f.attrs[str(target_name[0])]
    vecs2 = [f.attrs[str(name)] for name in target_names]

cosine_similarity(vec1[np.newaxis], vecs2)[0]

# 0.04-0.05 sec on my pc
ind1 = name_ind[target_name[0]]
inds2 = [name_ind[name] for name in target_names]

vec1 = mmap[ind1]
vecs2 = mmap[inds2]

cosine_similarity(vec1[np.newaxis], vecs2)[0]
```

Comment: What  is the max. size of  n and m? I guess you want to use HDF5 because you are running out of memory otherwise? And the last question: What do you want to do at the end with this huge array (maybe some kind of a reduction operation like max,min,sum)?

Comment: The `attrs` dictionary is meant to store added information, not the main data.  The parameters that you specify when creating the dataset (shape, dtype, compression) don't apply  You haven't stored anything in the dataset itself.

Comment: max9111, n is number of texts (about 17mln), m is a vector size equals to 150.

My goal is to calculate dot product of two matrices that are subset of the main matrix, e.g. (k, m) x (l, m).T
I tried to do it on the fly using pandas and fasttext (based on input data find row indices -> get texts -> convert it to m-size vectors -> find matrix dot product). It worked pretty slow, so I decided to precalculate text vectors and store them in hdf5 or memory-map.

Comment: hpaulj, I was sure that I did something wrong with attrs and create_dataset. Memory-map in my example worked pretty fast but I don't think it's the best way to solve my problem (described it in the comment above)